# Array comparison working in Chrome but not with Chrome IPAD

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, ipad

I am using **new_array.filter(val => !old_array.includes(val));** method to compare two array. It works fine in Chrome but not with chrome in IOS. Seems like and issue in => operator. Unfortunately debug mode is not available in IPAD which I am having. Is there any alternate for this.

Sathya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The alternative is not to use arrow functions (at least, not in the deployed version), which are a fairly new feature (although I'm very surprised to hear that Chrome for iOS doesn't support them; Chrome's underlying JavaScript engine has supported them for a long time).

To do that, you have two options:

1. Transpile with a tool like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) before you create the deployed version. That way you can happily use arrow functions and many (though not all) other features of ES2015 and after without worrying about support on older browsers.
2. Or to just address that one specific thing, use a `function` function:

   ```
   new_array.filter(function(val) { return !old_array.includes(val); });
   ```

   You're not using `this` or `super` or similar that you need to close over in the callback, so it doesn't have to be an arrow function.

Comment: I used 2nd option and works great. Thanks T.J. Crowder